# PowerShell launching alternative text editor

Tags: bash, powershell, git-bash

Launching notepad as a text editor in PowerShell is ' notepad README.txt ' but if I wish to use a different text editor (due to some obvious limitations to notepad) such as Notepad++ , How would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether Notepad++ is in your path or not. If it is in your path then just execute:

```
notepad++ readme.txt
```

Be aware that if you are in the same dir as notepad++ you must execute it like so (security feature):

```
.\notepad++ readme.txt
```

If not then you need to specify the path to notepad++ e.g.:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' readme.txt
```

If you do this a lot you may want to create an alias in your profile script e.g.:

```
New-Alias e 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe'
e readme.txt
```

Use whatever you want for the alias: ed, edit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above answer by @Kieth , I usually do the below to open a text file :

```
Invoke-Item C:\temp\test.txt
```

But the problem with this approach is by default .txt extension is associated to be opened by notepad.exe

One can set the default editor for a specific type (e.g .txt) type of files via the Explorer, CMD or PowerShell

**Via Explorer**

Right click on .txt file > Open With > Choose Default program > select Editor of choice.

**Via PowerShell/ CMD**

One can use the command line utility named **assoc** and **ftype** together for mapping the extension to a default program. First run assoc to get the file association

```
PS> cmd /c assoc .txt
```

> .txt=txtfile

Now we can set the default application (open commandstrings) for that filetype association.

```
    PS>cmd /c Ftype txtfile"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" %1
```

Once the file associations are made. Simply do the below:

```
PS> ii C:\Temp\test.txt # ii alias for Invoke-Item
```